# How to use map / flatMap on a scala Map?

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples, sequence, flatmap

I have two sequences, i.e. `prices: Seq[Price]` and `overrides: Seq[Override]`. I need to do some magic on them yet only for a subset based on a shared id.

So I grouped them both into a `Map` each via `groupBy`:

I do the group by via:

```
val pricesById = prices.groupBy(_.someId) // Int => Seq[Cruise]
val overridesById = overrides.groupBy(_.someId) // // Int => Seq[Override]
```

I expected to be able to create my wanted sequence via `flatMap`:

```
val applyOverrides = (someId: Int, prices: Seq[Price]): Seq[Price]  => {
  val applicableOverrides =  overridesById.getOrElse(someId, Seq())
  magicMethod(prices, applicableOverrides) // returns Seq[Price]
}

val myPrices: Seq[Price] = pricesById.flatMap(applyOverrides)
```

I expected `myPrices` to contain just one big `Seq[Price]`.

Yet I get a weird type mismatch within the flatMap method with NonInferedB I am unable to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, maps are tuples, not a key-value pair.

The function for `flatMap` hence expects only *one* parameter, namely the tuple `(key, value)`, and not two parameters `key, value`.

Since you can access first element of a tuple via `_1`, the second via `_2` and so on, you can generate your desired function like so:

```
val pricesWithMagicApplied = pricesById.flatMap(tuple => 
  applyOverrides(tuple._1, tuple._2)
```

Another approach is to use case matching:

```
val pricesWithMagicApplied: Seq[CruisePrice] = pricesById.flatMap {
  case (someId, prices) => applyOverrides(someId, prices)
}.toSeq
```

Comment: In Scala map is a collection of `Key and value` pairs. check the https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html